# PageSpeed insights Google

Tags: pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I have some problem with PageSpeed: Lighthouse returned an error:

> ERRORED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST. Не удалось загрузить страницу. Убедитесь,
>   что URL введен правильно и сервер отвечает на все запросы. Код
>   статуса: 403.

What I can do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use other browsers, I had same issue until I used chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue 'ERRORED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST' with the 503 error code on a wordpress site! The problem was the wordfence security plugin for me. When I deactivated the plugin the problem fixed.